# Best way to test if a commerce price field has a value

Tags: commerce

So I have an entity called "Discount" with the following fields:

- `field_discount_percentage` is an integer field.
- `field_discount_price` is a commerce price field.

I can test whether the percentage field contains a value to avoid exceptions via:

```
if (empty($discount_wrapper->field_discount_percentage))
```

However this does not work for commerce price fields, as `$discount_wrapper->field_discount_price` is an object in itself and so the following is always true:

```
if (empty($discount_wrapper->field_discount_price))
```

Alternatively I tried:

```
if (empty($discount_wrapper->field_discount_price->amount))
```

However this produces an exception on zero values, and the following:

```
if (empty($discount_wrapper->field_discount_price->value()))
```

Which returns a PHP Fatal error as `empty()` can only take variables and not functions.

I am now resorting to:

```
if ($discount_wrapper->field_discount_price->value())
```

However this does not feel explicit and I was hoping there is a more conventional means to test price fields.

Answer (score 0):

Adding [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)() to that last `if` statement is a bit more explicit.

```
if (isset($discount_wrapper->field_discount_price->value()))
```

Comment: That won't work as the call happens before isset, so you'll get an error anyways if the field is not existant.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're looking for but you've got `commerce_price_wrapper_value` function to extract a price from an entity in a consistent way, example:

```
$unit_price = commerce_price_wrapper_value($wrapper, 'commerce_unit_price', TRUE);
```

The third parameter is a boolean that indicates to return the default price structure.